# How to redirect output to screen as well as a file?

Tags: bash, redirect

My aim is to log all output from a script into a directory that the script is going to create.

For example, I have:

`~/.abc.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
rails new myapp
```

When I run...

```
cd ~/code
. ~/.abc.sh
```

...that will create a new Rails app in directory `~/code/myapp`.

When Rails is creating an app, it outputs a whole lot of text that I want to capture and store in a log file in the same directory the `rails` command newly created. I also want to display that text in the terminal as well.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the `tee` command for that:

```
command | tee /path/to/logfile
```

The equivelent without writing to the shell would be:

```
command > /path/to/logfile
```

If you want to append (`>>`) and show the output in the shell, use the `-a` option:

```
command | tee -a /path/to/logfile
```

Please note that the pipe will catch stdout only, errors to stderr are not processed by the pipe with `tee`. If you want to log errors (from stderr), use:

```
command 2>&1 | tee /path/to/logfile
```

This means: run `command` and redirect the stderr stream (2) to stdout (1). That will be passed to the pipe with the `tee` application.

Comment: Do you mean `~/.abc.sh | tee <file>` ? If so, then the trouble is I don't know in which directory the script is going to create the app when I call it, so how would I know what to give the in the `file` argument? (Thanks for the great examples)

Comment: @Zabba: what about creating a temporary file and move it afterwards?

Comment: Ok, that should work :). In regard to that, how do I create a temp file with a random name that I can then output to and then copy to a desired location afterwards? Is there some built-in command to get a "temp file name" ?

Comment: @Zabba: the command for that is `mktemp`. See the manual page [`man mktemp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/mktemp.1.html).

Comment: 跪拜, work like a charm

Comment: Does not work perfectly... it seems output is written only at certain times (may be after new line)....

Comment: To copy both stderr and stdout to a file while having output in the terminal you can also use: `command |& tee <file>`.

Answer (score 2):

[`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) will start an interactive session and log all the output (stdout/stderr etc) to a file, or (with the `-c` parameter) will run a command and log the output of that.

```
script -c ~/.abc.sh -f abc.log
```

Note: in an interactive session, you can stop recording just by exiting the session as you normally would (e.g. `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>).

For session recording with video playback, you can also try [asciinema](https://asciinema.org).