# Bash script output on the screen also to the log file

Tags: bash, scripts, log

I created a simple script that does a curl command ( I run it every month via crontab ) and I made it echo to a logfile with the date of run.
The problem is that I want to receive the shell script output as well to the log file and I'm sure quite sure how to achieve that.
This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
LOGFILE=/root/Delete-Old-Indices.log
#Nginx Logs - Delete older than 90 Days
curl -XDELETE XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
echo "$(date "+%d%m%Y %T") : Starting work" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

so now I only receive the following line of log in my log file: "Date + Time : Starting work" and I don't get the shell script output in my log file, I only see it in my shell window.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect output to screen as well as a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38126/how-to-redirect-output-to-screen-as-well-as-a-file)

Comment: `printf '%(%d%m%Y %T)T : %s\n' -1 "Starting work"` if you intend to  print a time string `printf` is a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect any output to the log file the way you did for the `echo` command, i.e., using the `>>` redirection symbol.

That would cause no output to be displayed anymore on the screen. If you wish to also see the output, you can use `tee` with the `-a` or `--append` option, as

```
curl -XDELETE XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | tee -a $LOGFILE
```

This redirects both to the file (appending to what is already there), and the screen.

If what you want is to collect all output from the script into a log file, then simply redirect the output while invoking the shell script. Within the script itself, you would then remove all redirection.

Comment: I was going to suggest using the redirection symbol `>>` in the `crontab` line with the bash script, but I like this solution better.

Comment: @user68186 you are right, and that is probably more what the user wants in this specific case: running from a cron tab, one never sees the screen output. Added this to the answer